# py2neo, create a node ? two ways?

Tags: py2neo

I am confused as what is the difference between below two ways to create a node ? It seems like the result is the same;

```
from py2neo import Graph
graph = Graph()

graph.cypher.execute("CREATE (a:Person {name:{N}})", {"N": "Alice"})  # a
graph.create( Node("Person",name="Alice"))  # b
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the py2neo v3 documentation, it seems there's yet a third way to create a node.

First instantiate a Node object, as in

```
a = Node("Person",name="Alice")
```

then insert it in a subgraph (see py2neo types),

```
sg = Subgraph(a)
```

then create elements of this subgraph (Graph.create method):

```
graph.create(sg)
```

I understand that subgraph creation should however be preferred when creating numerous nodes and edges (a subgraph ...).

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the result is exactly the same. Py2neo exposes two levels of API: a pure Cypher API (`execute`) and a simpler object-based API (`Node`). The latter is generally easier to get up and running with, the former is more comprehensive.